# How to pass a read-only vector<int> to a function which is part of a vector of pair<int,int> without copying

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of pairs of let's say `int`s. Now there is a library that expects a `const vector<int>&` reference as an input to one of its functions. Is there a way of passing the appropriate vector to the function without copying data? Because all solutions for extracting vectors here on SO always deal with the scenario that I need to extract and copy parts of the vector, but I don't want to copy as I only pass the subvector as read-only const.

Note: I cannot change the function I am calling (that expects `const vector<int>&`) as it is not part of my code.

**EDIT:** As I was not clear what I actually want to extract, I will try to clarify. I have a `vector<pair<A,B>>` and want to pass `vector<A>`.

Comment: The in-memory layout isn't the same for the data, so you can't even come up with a non-safe kludge. Sorry.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I think the underlying data *will* (probably) have the same layout.  For `std::pair<int,int> p`.  `(&p.first)+1` and `&p.second` are overwhelmingly likely to be equal (although the standard doesn't guarantee that).

Comment: I don't get it. If you have `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> { {0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5} }`, what should you pass to the library function? `{0, 2, 4}`? `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`?

Comment: @MartinBonner it depends on how you read the question. If the intent is to send *both* of the pair to the function, then you might be right. If the intent is to send *one* of the pair, it can't be done.

Comment: @YSC I actually don't have integers (this was just an example) but I have openCL Devices and for each device there is also a CommandQueue. And I store them in a vector of tuple<Device, CommandQueue> right now, but one function wants a vector<Device>. So basically I want a vector of the first elements of each tuple.

Comment: Then there is no solution without altering your internal structure. Can you use something different from `std::vector<std::tuple<Device, CommandQueue>>`?

Comment: @YSC I am not bound to use tuple. I just couldn't come up with something that would keep the connection between the Device and CommanQueue as well as the tuple does, except writing my own container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  `std::vector<std::pair<int>>` and `std::vector<int>` are completely unrelated types.  You can't pass one where the function requires the other.  You will have to copy the data.

This is slightly sad because the vector of pairs must have an array of adjacent pairs, and in reality, the pairs will just contain adjacent `int`s, so the memory layout you need is there.  The truth is though, that there is no way to get at it.

**Edit**
I see from comments that it's more like `std::pair<int, char*>` in which case you are really stuck.

I think "write your own container" which can expose a `std::vector<int> const&` for use in this other function, or just copy, is your best bet.

Comment: Ok. So maybe there is another way if I do not use `std::pair`? I mean I could just store two separate vectors, but that would be really uncomfortable as I usually (except for this one function call) need both elements of the pair. So is there maybe a clever way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `vector<int>` to store your data, and write an adapter class which will expose it using interface compatible with `vector<pair<int,int>>` for your code.

Answer (score 0):

What about something in the taste of:

```
class container : private std::tuple<std::vector<Device>, std::vector<CommandQueue>>
{
public:
    std::tuple<Device, CommandQueue> tuple(size_t index)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(get<0>.at(index), get<1>.at(index))
    }

    const std::vector<Device>&       devices()      const { return get<0>; }
    const std::vector<CommandQueue>& commandQueue() const { return get<1>; }
};
```

Comment: Hm, but I think the original construct is more comfortable if I want to iterate over the tuple<Device, CommandQueue>, which I do a lot. I would rather copy the devices from time to time then, I guess.